# onBackPressed doesn't work with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My code displays an AlertDialog, which exits the activity by pressing the positive button. I want it to be able to exit on back button as well. But my onBackPressed does not work when I have `.setCancelable(false)` . How do I fix this without changing it to `.setCancelable(true)`

```
// show in dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("BROADCAST")
            .setMessage(text)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: So you want to close the activity on a back press if the dialog is opened?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: finish replace with dismiss

Comment: If you don't set set cancelable to true, activity will never receive the onbackpressed callback when user presses back button. I wonder there is really a way to do this

Comment: I had the same problem. But I was programming in Kotlin. If somebody uses Kotlin, my question will help him/her:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462748/not-working-onbackpressed-when-setcancelable-of-alertdialog-is-false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

easy peeasy..

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("BROADCAST")
        .setMessage(text)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
        .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
alert.show();
```

For answer in Kotlin see here:[Not working onbackpressed when setcancelable of alertdialog is false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60462748/12478830)

Comment: why down vote he want to close activity with either positive button either back pressed, this code does same thing. just set `cancelable(true)`... it will receive on dismiss... and `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: I was actually trying to do the exact same thing you did but I was bombed with errors. I don't understand why people are so ignorant. This is the right solution.

Comment: Cause I manipulated the answer you want to `setCancelable(false)`. I chenged `setCancelable(true)`. they downvoted me

Comment: In the question it is mentioned that how to achieve this without setcancelable(true)... I guess the down vote is because of that...however your answer is correct. I could not understand how this answer has been accepted. According to the question, @Majeed khan answer seems convincing

Comment: @7383 acutally my answer fulfill his need. he asked wrong question his question should be close activity either positive button clicked or dialog closed.

Comment: I had the same problem. But I was programming in Kotlin. If somebody uses Kotlin, my question will help him/her:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462748/not-working-onbackpressed-when-setcancelable-of-alertdialog-is-false

Answer (score 4):

you can set a key listener

```
builder.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                        dialog.dismiss(); // dismiss the dialog
                       YourActivity.this.finish(); // exits the activity

                    }

                    return true;
                }
            })
```

Comment: this is not how it works, dialog can override back button and onBackPressed

Comment: It would probably work, but not when an AlertDialog is being displayed

Comment: eidted the answer if you want to exit the activity then you can simply do it by getting the activity instance and calling finsih() on the instance

Comment: and one more thing! AlertDialog does not override the onBackPressed! it is overridden by the activity itself.

Comment: I had the same problem. But I was programming in Kotlin. If somebody uses Kotlin, my question will help him/her:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462748/not-working-onbackpressed-when-setcancelable-of-alertdialog-is-false