# Not working onbackpressed when setcancelable of alertdialog is false

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, back, onbackpressed

I have an AlertDialog and its `setCancelable()` is false. In `Onbackpressed` function I want the AlertDialog to be closed. But when `setCancelable()` is false, the back key doesn't work at all. What should I do to get rid of this problem? I don't want to change `setCancelable()` to true because I will have another problem.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Check your internet connection")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.setCancelable(false)
            .create().show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with code

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251122/5343866 answer your question?

Comment: Hey @MohammadMoeinGolchin, you need to stop talking about upvoting and downvoting. This habit is heavily frowned upon on StackOverflow. Allow users to vote at their own discretion; you don't need to talk about votes at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just add a onKeyListener and cancel dialog on back key event.

```kotlin
    lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Check your internet connection")
                .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }.setCancelable(false)
                .create()
        dialog.show()

        dialog.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, _ ->
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if(dialog.isShowing) {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this code for both alert-dialog and custom-dialog?

Comment: this is for alert dialog

Comment: I think you said vice versa. It has problem for alert dialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209659/discussion-between-alif-hasnain-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Comment: happy to be useful :)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest work-around for this problem is to set an `OnKeyListener` and automatically detect when the user hits the back button.

**Java:**

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

  dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          dialog.cancel;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
  });

  return dialog;
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
    dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
    dialog.show()

    dialog.setOnKeyListener (object : Dialog.OnKeyListener { 
      override fun onKey(dialogInterface: DialogInterface, keyCode: Int, keyEvent: KeyEvent) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK and keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            dialog.dismiss()
            true
        }
        false
      }})
```

Note that I added an extra condition in the if-statement, all this does is to make sure this does not fire twice.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Is my code in Java that you answered me in Java?!@Taslim Oseni

Comment: I have added a Kotlin solution. ;-)

Comment: What kind of error you getting in -Taslim Oseni answer @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: Copy and paste his code in Android Studio. You will see the error@Ali

Comment: Are you sure? Has it any change?@TaslimOseni

Comment: Yes it has, friend.

Answer (score 5):

As i see you create dialogBuilder is public why not you call this in a public alertDialog and than show it using alertDilog.show() and  close on back pressClick in activity and dismiss the dialog alertDilog.dismiss() override the onBackPress and dismiss it here

```
val alertDialog:AlertDialog?=null


         alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        //set icon 
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        //set title
        .setTitle("Are you sure to Exit")
        //set message
        .setMessage("Exiting will call finish() method")
        //set positive button
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //set what would happen when positive button is clicked    
            finish();
        }
        })
        //set negative button
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //set what should happen when negative button is clicked
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing 
          Happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        })
        .show();

       onBackPress(){alertDialog.dismiss()}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dialogBuilder.setOnKeyListener(object : OnKeyListener() {
            fun onKey(dialog: DialogInterface, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
//if you want to cancel the dialog only
                    dialog.cancel()
                    //if you want to finish then 
                   // finish()
                }
                return true
            }
        })
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209657/discussion-on-answer-by-wahdat-kashmiri-not-working-onbackpressed-when-setcancel).

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to close the dialog when touched outside area of the dialog, you can set the property

```
    permissionDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

and if you want to dismiss the dialog on backpress you need to call the method on keyListener

```
 permissionDialog?.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, _ ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            dialog?.dismiss()
            true
        }
        false
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Raza, my code is in Kotlin, this code may work correctly in Java.

Comment: permissionDialog is my alert dialog?

Comment: instead of dialog builder , you should use customDialog with layout.

Comment: and yes permissionDialog is alertDialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209750/discussion-between-mohammadmoeingolchin-and-raza).